# Ng-repeat without freezing UI on over 12k records

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have over 12k images mostly 10x10 size converted to base64 in a json array,
and i have the size of the image in the json and x,y coordinates where i want to show the image on the screen,
the json look like this

```
[{"id":"1","width":"10","height":"10","image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAIAAAACUFjqAAABFElEQVQYlTWNzUvCcByHP9+x1c9kMv3Jei8J\/QMibHQKSvrjoqCTV2\/dugcdY5CXFaH04hz4lhrl\/G3lVgPXQXuODw88dH33sJYqAPCpywmfMQBwwu90481rUBDEMcOMBAAgAPwo1hVy3W8ZCCkEAMYYgAmCr2ieR2ogj12xsro86A8BITxhOR0AmUz2mXxqDiQpq79HsbuYPjs\/tZzOcenItIPyZaWY0jeLJdlsCQDtUW1r74Abh2ZLeLbnOUlO2M1rdFG9Xegm57Of5usHKxjaSX6fq8q99UjlK2tnXQIw4duzqD2qNarjip+APZHrvV69N\/Md\/FMwtJuUntZzZD69AEjrOQBcVVSFKAwZmwJLg\/7wD2cKcW+hz09jAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC","title":"Sovereign Grace Ministries","url":"http:\/\/www.sovereigngraceministries.org\/","order_id":"6106","x":"0","y":"0"}....
```

now im showing these images on Ionic1 AngularJS Mobile Application

ng-repeat looks like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div ng-click="showModal({{ad.order_id}})" ng-repeat="ad in mainBillboard" style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,{{ad.image}});width:{{ad.width}}px;height:{{ad.height}}px;top:{{ad.y}}px;left:{{ad.x}}px"></div>
</div>
```

I used base64 for fast loading of image which worked for me and #wrapper position is set to relative, now the result looks like this

[image]

its a small screenshot of the screen just for an idea

problem is, during np-repeat even the loader on the screen freezed for few seconds until the UI gets updated, all i want is the loader to keep running until the ng-repeat finish

i have found similar problems with ng-repeat but nothing seem to solve my problem

Comment: Why would you want to render 12k images at once? Use paging, lazy load or virtual scroll.

Comment: thats the reason i posted a small screenshot, its a billboard made with multiple images

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collection-repeat`. It is optimized for Ionic Frameworks.

You can read about it [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/).

Something like this:

```
collection-repeat="item in items"
```

Comment: How can they use it? This answer seems incomplete.

Comment: Instead of using `ng-repeat` they should write it with `collection-repeat`

Comment: problem: i am also using ion-scroll for xy scrolling and when i changed to collection-repeat it shows this error on console "collection-repeat expected a parent x or y scrollView, not an xy scrollView." and even if i set it to x  then it shows another error "ERR_INVALID_URL" because im using base64 url "background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,{{ad.image}})"

Comment: @WasifKhalil It should not happen that way. Can you please check your syntax? collection-repeat works same like ngrepeat but performance wise it is better.

Comment: but i guess it doesnt work with ion-scroll set to direction="xy" and base64 image url, the only thing i changed was collection-repeat so im sure no syntax problem